# angular 8 @ViewChild returns undefined

Tags: angular, viewchild

I'm trying to use angular 8 @ViewChild to variables from one component to another but it is producing undefined

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../styles/css/main.css']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {
  isAuthenticated: any = false;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and I wanna use isAuthenticated variable inside navbar component from signinComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SigninComponent } from "../signin/signin.component";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../styles/css/main.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  isAuthenticated: any;
  @ViewChild(SigninComponent, {static: false}) signReference !: SigninComponent;



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isAuthenticated = this.signReference.isAuthenticated
    console.log(this.isAuthenticated)
  }

}
```

This is navbar.component.html and it is containing isAuthenticated variable to validate some item of the navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Mango App</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle">
            <i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" *ngIf="isAuthenticated">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Posts</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Messages</a>
                </li>
            </ul>


            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" *ngIf="!isAuthenticated">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a routerLink="/signup" class="nav-link">SignUp</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a routerLink="/signin" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" *ngIf="isAuthenticated">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Change Password</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a routerLink="/signup" class="nav-link">Logout</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

how to deal with this error in angular 8

Comment: Can you show us `navbar.component.html`?

Comment: yes i have post as a comment

Comment: You have actually added it as an answer. I suggest you delete the answer and edit your question instead.

Comment: I don't see any `<app-signin>` element inside your navbar template, so navbar has no ViewChild of `SigninComponent` class. Hence undefined.

Comment: thank you, boss, it worked for me